# How do you reload your .vimrc file without restarting vim?

Tags: vim, vimrc

Can you edit your `.vimrc` file and reload it without having to restart Vim?

Answer (score 750, accepted):

If you're editing it, you can reload it with:

```
:so %
```

`%` stands for current file name (see `:h current-file`) and `:so` is short for `:source`, which reads the content of the specified file and treats it as Vim code.

In general, to re-load the currently active .vimrc, use the following (see [Daily Vim](http://dailyvim.blogspot.com/2008/11/reload-vimrc.html)):

```
:so $MYVIMRC
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803464/how-do-i-source-something-in-my-vimrc-file

Comment: and `:so ~/.vimrc` should work too on unix

Comment: :so ~/_vimrc works on windows.  Of course, I keep my _vimrc in my windows home directory, or else this won't work.  To see what Vim considers your home directory, use `:echo expand("~")`.

Comment: Note that if keyboard mappings were already in place, then they will not erased even if they are deleted from the new vimrc

Comment: Or `:so ~/.vim/gvimrc` or wherever you put it of course

Comment: Can we somehow fully flush the user config while running vim, THEN load the user config again?

Comment: Is this supported on overleaf.com?  Seems it ain't on repl.it

Answer (score 82):

Even better, you configure Vim to watch for changes in your `.vimrc` and automatically reload the config.

```
augroup myvimrc
    au!
    au BufWritePost .vimrc,_vimrc,vimrc,.gvimrc,_gvimrc,gvimrc so $MYVIMRC | if has('gui_running') | so $MYGVIMRC | endif
augroup END
```

Source: [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2403926/261251)

Note: this particular method watches for the many variations of Vim config filenames so that it's compatible with GUI Vim, Windows Vim, etc.

Comment: How performant is this method?

Comment: I find that use this kind of command sometimes hangs my nvim for a few seconds or longer.

Answer (score 15):

### Key mappings

```
" Quickly edit/reload this configuration file
nnoremap gev :e $MYVIMRC<CR>
nnoremap gsv :so $MYVIMRC<CR>
```

### Completely automated solution

To **automatically** reload upon save, add the following to your `$MYVIMRC`:

```
if has ('autocmd') " Remain compatible with earlier versions
 augroup vimrc     " Source vim configuration upon save
    autocmd! BufWritePost $MYVIMRC source % | echom "Reloaded " . $MYVIMRC | redraw
    autocmd! BufWritePost $MYGVIMRC if has('gui_running') | so % | echom "Reloaded " . $MYGVIMRC | endif | redraw
  augroup END
endif " has autocmd
```

and then for the last time, type:

```
:so %
```

The next time you save your `vimrc`, it will be automatically reloaded.

**Features:**

- Tells the user what has happened (also logging to `:messages`)
- Handles various names for the configuration files
- Ensures that it wil only match the actual configuration file (ignores copies in other directories, or a `fugitive://` diff)
- Won't generate an error if using `vim-tiny`

Of course, the automatic reload will only happen if you edit your `vimrc` in vim.

Comment: where will be the `echom` message be displayed?

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to remembering/typing `:so $MYVIMRC` is these mappings. It lets you quickly edit vimrc (`ev`) or source vimrc (`sv`).

```
" Quickly open/reload vim
nnoremap <leader>ev :split $MYVIMRC<CR>  
nnoremap <leader>sv :source $MYVIMRC<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different version of ReloadVimrcFunction

```
" Reloads vimrc after saving it but keep cursor position
if !exists('*ReloadVimrcFunction')
    function! ReloadVimrcFunction()
        let save_cursor = getcurpos()
        source $MYVIMRC | windo redraw
        call setpos('.', save_cursor)
        echom "Reloaded $MYVIMRC"
    endfunction
endif
noremap <silent> <Leader>v :drop $MYVIMRC<cr>
command! -nargs=0 ReloadVimrc :call ReloadVimrcFunction()
nnoremap <silent> <C-s> :call ReloadVimrcFunction()<CR>
```

In order to avoid loading the function twice we set:

```
if !exists('*ReloadVimrcFunction')
```

We also save the cursor position because it would be anoying to have our cursor positioning changing every time we reload `$MYVIMRC`.

I also have an augroup to trigger this function each time I save $MYVIMRC

```
augroup Reload
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost $MYVIMRC call ReloadVimrcFunction()
augroup END
```