# How to reload vundle plugin after configuration change

Tags: vim

I am using Vim with Vundle and I just changed a plugin specific setting in my .vimrc:

```
let g:NERDTreeWinSize = 60
```

How do I reload the plugin to pick up this setting(s) without restarting vim?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most plugins directly use the configuration variables, so it suffices to apply the variable setting to the current Vim session, and then re-trigger the plugin.

---

For the first, you can either re-source your entire `~/.vimrc` (if it's clean, and you avoid re-defining autocmds twice):

```
:source ~/.vimrc
```

(You can abbreviate that as `:so %` if you're currently editing it.) Or you just selectively execute the changed line, e.g. via:

```
yy:@"
```

---

For NERD_tree and this particular config, retriggering can be done via:

1. closing and reopening NERD_tree
2. zooming the NERD_tree window in and out

Comment: How does one "zoom" in and out of a window (this is not the same as ctrl+w+w)?

Comment: See `:h NERDTree-A`; this expands the sidebar window (for long filenames / deep trees).

Comment: Short form of `:source ~/.vimrc` is `:so ~/.vimrc`. If you are currently editing `~/.vimrc` you can [just run](https://superuser.com/a/132030/139893) `:so %`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that a restarting the plugin (in this case :NERDTree) with the basic start command was enough hence this was my solution:

Edit .vimrc

```
let g:NERDTreeWinSize = 60
```

Save .vimrc

```
:w
```

Reload .vimrc as source

```
:source %
```

Run :NERDTree

```
:NERDTree
```